# How to Copy data from view to table by using trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In Sql server 2012 Database I have Two tables and SalesMan and Employee,and also combine these two tables to create a view to show Data of both tables combinely my task is to when employee and sales man insert values in there particular tables it will come in views... its ok iam done but i want to show view data into another  third table Called ZongSalesRecord... by using trigger when a values come in a view it will automatically come in 3rd table...

Problem is that when i run trigger values dont show in my 3rd table..Please Help

```
create trigger tr2  // trriger name
on salesview  // view Name
instead of insert 
as begin

    insert into ZongSalesRecord // third table in which i want to show data from view
    select * from inserted

end
```

Comment: You should list the columns explicitly in the `insert` and `select` statements.

Comment: Why do you need to put it into a table? Why can't you just use the view? Performance? You want to insert into the view? Why do you think you need to put it in a table?

Comment: That trigger is only called when you try and insert into the view. Is that what you're doing? You definitely need to put an insert and select list in there as already stated

Comment: In general, don't *store* data that you can easily *calculate* from already stored data. If this is performance related, you may be looking for *indexed views* where SQL Server automatically persists the content of the view but takes care of maintenance automatically.

Comment: You have to put the trigger in the underlying table. Is can't see why one would need a trigger that works only when the table is updated through one specific view.